# Moving Data from one table to another

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataadapter

Hie frnds,

I have two tables say "Orders" and "OrdersXML"

now I wish to remove orders which are more than 7 days old to OrdersXML table which i have done using **sql adapter** update function over dataset, which do this job taking 100 rows at a time.
I want to delete the rows from the orders table which have been moved to OrdersXML table
How can i Achieve this?? I want to ensure that a row in Orders is only deleted after it has been inserted into OrdersXML. I don't want to loose any of the data.. not even by accident..

Should I use trigger? or should i code it in C# itself?

as m using data-adapter I cant get the ids which have been inserted if any exception comes in between.. can i??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write the SQL with a script, use a SqlCommand with a SQL transaction:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

-- Copy rows from Orders to OrdersXML

-- Delete rows from Orders that were copied

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

If you want to do this with objects and code, use a [SqlTransaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.aspx) object:

```
// code sample adapted from MSDN
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction");
    SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.Transaction = transaction;

    try
    {
        command.CommandText = "TODO"; // Copy rows from Orders to OrdersXML
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command.CommandText = "TODO"; // Delete copied rows from Orders
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // Attempt to commit the transaction.
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        try
        {
            // Attempt to roll back the transaction.
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
            // This catch block will handle any errors that may have occurred
            // on the server that would cause the rollback to fail, such as
            // a closed connection.
        }
    }
```

Comment: That was really good.. please explain a bit what is "TODO" means, Do i need to put my t-sql query there..

Comment: why do it as a copy+delete when you can do it in a single command? see my answer for how.

Comment: @Sirwani - Yes, the "TODO" is your SQL (that I assume you already have) to perform the copy and delete. Since you did not post the schema for Orders or OrdersXML, I didn't try to put the SQL for the copy and delete.

Comment: @KM the single command is good as well, and it is probably the fastest method. I assumed the OP already had SQL for the copy and delete, so it is easy to wrap it with a transaction. If there are other operations besides the basic copy and delete (in other words, operations requiring more an a single statement), then you will probably need a transaction.

Comment: Selected as used transaction thing really helps

Answer (score 2):

use **DELETE** with an **OUTPUT** clause and do it in one statement:

```
DECLARE @OldTable table(col1 int, col2    varchar(5), col3 char(5), col4     datetime)
DECLARE @NewTable table(col1 int, column2 varchar(5), col3 int    , col_date char(23), extravalue int, othervalue varchar(5))
INSERT @OldTable VALUES (1 , 'AAA' ,'A'  ,'1/1/2010'           )
INSERT @OldTable VALUES (2 , 'BBB' ,'12' ,'2010-02-02 10:11:22')
INSERT @OldTable VALUES (3 , 'CCC' ,null ,null                 )
INSERT @OldTable VALUES (4 , 'B'   ,'bb' ,'2010-03-02'         )

DELETE /*top (1000)*/ @OldTable
    OUTPUT DELETED.col1
          ,DELETED.col2
          ,CASE
               WHEN ISNUMERIC(DELETED.col3)=1 THEN DELETED.col3 
               ELSE NULL END
          ,DELETED.col4
          ,CONVERT(varchar(5),DELETED.col1)+'!!'
        INTO @NewTable (col1, column2, col3, col_date, othervalue)
    OUTPUT 'Rows Deleted: ', DELETED.* --this line returns a result set shown in the OUTPUT below
    WHERE col1 IN (2,4)

SELECT * FROM @NewTable
```

output:

```
               col1        col2  col3  col4
-------------- ----------- ----- ----- -----------------------
Rows Deleted:  2           BBB   12    2010-02-02 10:11:22.000
Rows Deleted:  4           B     bb    2010-03-02 00:00:00.000

(2 row(s) affected)

col1        column2 col3        col_date                extravalue  othervalue
----------- ------- ----------- ----------------------- ----------- ----------
2           BBB     12          Feb  2 2010 10:11AM     NULL        2!!
4           B       NULL        Mar  2 2010 12:00AM     NULL        4!!

(2 row(s) affected)
```

You can use the `TOP (...)` to limit it as necessary.

Comment: This is a very good mechanism to copy and delete data in a single statement.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally recommend writing a stored procedure, so that you don't have the latency of using a C# client. You can then write a script to call this stored procedure every day or whatever.

Look up "Transactions", you can make it so that if one part of the query fails (i.e. the insert), then the rest of the query rolls back to the previous good state.